# Windows not letting me delete node_modules from desktop

Tags: windows, npm

I accidentally installed a bunch of packages to my desktop.

I tried to delete the node_modules file however it did not give me permission.[image]

I opened permissions and it told me I need permission from DESKTOP with a bunch of random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used VS Code for deleting node_modules , you can try by downloading the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wscats.delete-node-modules)

Comment: This answer is partially correct, I opened up Desktop with VSCode and simply just deleted node modules, no extension needed. I would love if someone explained why VSCode can delete node_modules but not me.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, but using extension it will delete faster.

Answer (score 1):

you are log in but not using the User account that created the folder, or the ownership is modified, you can log in with higher priviledge and do as [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed)